# Cakephp 3.0 Not saving DATE and TIME on Associated data model in an Add action

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I'm trying to make some kind of custom calendar system in CakePHP. What I'm trying to do is add an `agendascreen_activity` Model (of which all the fields already get saved correctly) and an associated model `agendascreen_no_repetitions` which has an id time, date and a FK pointing to the activity.

My problem is that the date and time fields don't get saved properly

here is my code so far:

**In my add.ctp file:**

```
<?= $this->Form->input('agendascreen_no_repetitions.date', ['type' => 'date']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('agendascreen_no_repetitions.time', ['type' => 'time']) ?>
```

**In my controller:**

```
public function add()
    {
        $agendascreenActivity = $this->AgendascreenActivities->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $agendascreenActivity = $this->AgendascreenActivities->patchEntity($agendascreenActivity, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->AgendascreenActivities->save($agendascreenActivity)) {

                $this->Flash->success(__('The agendascreen activity has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The agendascreen activity could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $agendascreens = $this->AgendascreenActivities->Agendascreens->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $this->set(compact('agendascreenActivity', 'agendascreens'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['agendascreenActivity']);
    }
```

The datatypes of the fields of the MySql DB are `DATE` and `TIME`

In the CakePHP debugger I can see that all the data is being sent correctly in the POST().

[image: See picture]

However when I look at the result, it adds the agendascreen_no_repetitions record two times with `null` as value for the date and the time.

[image: See picture]

After ndm's comment I checked if the data was being patched to the entity correctly.

I noticed that the `time` and `date` contents were directly under the `agendascreen_no_repetitions` object. instead of under `time` and `date`.

[image]

I tried the following:

```
<?= $this->Form->input('agendascreen_no_repetitions[0].date', ['type' => 'date']) ?>
        <?= $this->Form->input('agendascreen_no_repetitions[0].time', ['type' => 'time']) ?>
```

which resulted in the following:

[image]

Comment: Those are some funky Table class names.

Comment: @DavidYell I know, I didn't choose the names ;)

Comment: You'll have to do some more debugging, start with checking whether the data is correctly being patched into the entity (`debug($agendascreenActivity)`). If it's not, then the problem is most likely to be with marshalling. If it is, then you'll have to dig into the saving process, I'd start with checking what the insert query looks like.

Comment: @ndm I updated the question with the results of the debugging.

Comment: So `agendascreen_no_repetitions` is the property for a `hasMany` association? Your new example should work then - looking at the `time` property, it seems to do so.

Comment: the relations in my entity were hasmany for some reason, changing them to hasone and changing the properties in the add.ctp to agendascreen_no_repetition.time resolved the problem. Thanks @ndm!